# Div under body, generated by PHP, doesn't show in DOM. Why?

Tags: php

The `<div id="page>`" and `<div id="pagecontent">` don't show in on my webpage. In Firebug, the "Script" tab shows that index.php has both of these divs in it, but the HTML tab doesn't show either div. Why?

All of the content is generated by PHP, and everything shows correctly on the page except for these two divs. Both divs are immediately after the `<body>` tag. The active website with this problem [can be found here](http://poetryslam.myartsonline.com/contests.php).

HTML document:

```
<?php include "topofpage.php" ?>

        <!--Main Content Area-->
        <div id="main">

   <!-- TABLE HTML GOES HERE, BUT IT'S KINDA LONG AND BORING AND THE PROBLEM ISN'T HERE SO I TOOK IT OUT -->

            <!--Copyright Notice-->
            <p><br />
            <div id="divdate">&#169; 2009-2025 Poet Slam. All rights reserved.</div><br />
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var divisiondate=document.getElementById("divdate"); var newdater=new Date(); var years=newdater.getFullYear(); divisiondate.innerHTML="&#169; 2013-"+years+"  Poet Slam. All rights reserved.";
            </script>

    </div> <!-- THIS CLOSES THE <DIV ID="PAGECONTENT"> CREATED IN THE EXTERNAL PHP FILE
    </div> <!--THIS CLOSES THE <DIV ID="PAGE"> CREATED IN THE EXTERNAL PHP FILE

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's a small thing, but looking at line 49 in the page source you have an unclosed comment
`<!--CREATE A POEM * TAG DRAG AND DROP->`
Running the page as it stands through the W3CValidator - http://validator.w3.org/ - shows that causes a few errors that might be throwing the DOM parser.
As a first step I'd suggest fixing that, and iterating through the validator to at least knock off the (unexpected) errors

Comment: Thank you so much! I was literally staring at the answer for 5 hours today but was too stupid to realize my mistake! I'm sorry I can't, but I would upvote you if I had enough reputation!

Comment: I've been in exactly the same boat ;) glad I could help. Votes are cool, but even cooler is if you ever get a chance to help someone else here

Comment: srry- one more question! The program works when a user isn't logged in, but when someone logs in to the website the webpage freaks out and leaves about 100px of space between the top of the page and the body. I'm not sure how to fix this- if you could find anything in the W3 Validator that I'm not seeing please let me know! thanks

Comment: when you are logged in the CSS for #main seems to gain an extra `margin-top:150px` ... turning that off makes things look good again. BTW validation on the signup forgets everything on an error (annoying!)

Comment: k thx i'll fix that- and lol yeah i read your post about registration forms- i agree completely